# OpenLayers 3 ol.source.xyz set custom origin

Tags: openlayers, tile-map-service, tile-server

I am using local tiles from my file system in OpenLayers 3 (ol.source.xyz), and my local tiles are stored as  0/0/0.png and so on. Now the thing is that when I use these tiles on my map it starts from the top left corner (0,0), instead of I want to set custom origin of my tiles, is there any way to change the origin (instead of 0,0, I want to use my own custom coordinates).

Here is my code:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use a custom `tilegrid` within your tile source configuration , and set the `origin`

api doc [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/apidoc/ol.tilegrid.TileGrid.html)

and example [here](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/wmts-ign.html?q=tilegrid)

Answer (score 0):

Updated link as of 2021: [api docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_tilegrid_TileGrid-TileGrid.html) & [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-ign.html)  as a follow-up to @pavols answer above.